# What is the best Salesforce ODBC Driver?

Tags: integration

As per this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqquAAC), there is currently no Salesforce native ODBC driver.

There seem to be a few vendors all with a similar price point.

There is [Easysoft](http://www.odbc.org/products/data_access/odbc-salesforce-driver/index.html), then [cdata](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/salesforce/order/odbc/) and also [devart](https://www.devart.com/odbc/salesforce/ordering.html).

Which vendor would you recommend? Are there any particular unique selling points to using one of these ODBC's over another?

Comment: Is ODBC still a thing? Now where did I put that floppy disc... :D. Seriously though, might there be better options these days, what client are you wanting to use?

Comment: I think Progress software also has a Salesforce ODBC driver.

Comment: What do you need this driver for?

Comment: if you need this from excel, there are other options